# Python - check status of "Ok" or "Cancel" box in Windows

Tags: python, macros, pyautogui

I'm using Python to automate a longwinded and boring process with the help of automate the boring stuff. I'm essentially using it as a macro to do my job for me with a series of Pyautogui commands to create PDFs using a program and then sorting these out using PyPDF2. It's to create performance files for different airports. Different airports however have varying number of runways and as such take a varying amount of time to complete.

So, is there a way of waiting until the 'Ok' box shown below becomes available to be pressed using Python?

[Cancel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se41O.png)

[Ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ck5F.png)

At the minute I'm just taking the worst case scenario and pausing the script for the time taken for the airport with the most runways (around 90 seconds), however some airports complete in 10 seconds so there is a lot of time wasted here.

```
        time.sleep(15)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found it very difficult to find a method to check if the button was available to be pressed or not (Cancel or OK). I instead looked to find other indicators that the calculation was done. I came across winGuiAuto which had some really useful features in pulling text and other things from a window.

[winGuiAuto](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/winGuiAuto.py.html)

There were two tools required - finding the hwnd of the window as shown in the question and then pulling the text. These were

```
findTopWindow
dumpWindow
```

As an example I've displayed the output from the window while the program is running and once it was completed.

Running:

```
[[3736670, 'OK', 'Button'], [1180838, 'Cancel', 'Button'], [3737440, 'Calculating:  EGCC 05LAFTMP', 'Static'], [1050590, 'Start Calc:', 'Static'], [3999714, 'End Calc:', 'Static'], [4392774, 'Total Calc:', 'Static'], [8390102, 'Status:', 'Static'], [6489324, 'Calculation Time', 'Button'], [7997044, '12:47:02', 'Static'], [9242260, '12:47:11', 'Static'], [4589322, '', 'Static'], [4851642, 'Progress1', 'msctls_progress32'], [2885686, '--', 'Static']]
```

Completed:

```
[[3736670, 'OK', 'Button'], [1180838, 'Cancel', 'Button'], [3737440, 'Calculation Finished.', 'Static'], [1050590, 'Start Calc:', 'Static'], [3999714, 'End Calc:', 'Static'], [4392774, 'Total Calc:', 'Static'], [8390102, 'Status:', 'Static'], [6489324, 'Calculation Time', 'Button'], [7997044, '12:47:02', 'Static'], [9242260, '12:48:05', 'Static'], [4589322, '00:01:03', 'Static'], [4851642, 'Progress1', 'msctls_progress32'], [2885686, '/', 'Static']]
```

As you can see the 'Calculating:' became 'Calculation Finished.'

The solution was to implement a checking statement that would only allow the macro to progress once the calculation was finished.

```
        hwnd = findTopWindow('Calculating')

        while True:
            data = dumpWindow(hwnd)
            if data[2][1] == 'Calculation Finished.':
                break`enter code here`
```